# Javascript error in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

The code:

```
if(e.target.className.indexOf('box') !== -1)
  e.target.parentNode.className = 'boxW';
```

gets me this error in Internet Explorer 9:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'className'

Same thing happens for the parentNode property (if I remove the IF)...

Comment: IE9 finally implements the `addEventListener()` model, so you can just use `this` inside the callback rather than `e.target` / `e.srcElement`.

Comment: actually it doesnt work. I had the same problem with addEventListener and I used attachEvent..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how it is with IE 9 but other version have used `e.srcElement` instead of `e.target`.

So maybe you can do it like this:

```
var real_target = e.target || e.srcElement;

if(real_target.className.indexOf('box') !== -1)
  real_target.parentNode.className = 'boxW';
```